# Вывод скопированного текста на место курсора по кнопке android

Tags: java, android

У меня есть скопированный текст в буфере, мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку send_btn выводился текст в место где сейчас стоит курсор, по скольку это браузер я не могу задать определенное textview. Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Для копирования текста в буффер используйте такой вариант:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("your_text_to_be_copied");
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

Для получения текста используйте такой вариант:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
String pasteData = "";

 // If it does contain data, decide if you can handle the data.
if (!(clipboard.hasPrimaryClip())) {

} else if (!(clipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN))) {

    // since the clipboard has data but it is not plain text

} else {

    //since the clipboard contains plain text.
    ClipData.Item item = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);

    // Gets the clipboard as text.
    pasteData = item.getText().toString(); 
}
```

[Первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177231/android-copy-paste-from-clipboard-manager)